# Whitelist virtual_alias_maps

Tags: debian, alias, postfix

I have one mailbox in postfix and several aliases to it. Is it possible to create whitelists for specific alias in order to allow only the addresses from the list to send messages.

For example:

virtual hash:

```
test@example.com user
priv@example.com user
```

I would like to permit only two users(ali@comp.com ola@test.org), to send a message to priv@example.com In the other hand when someone wants to send a message to test@example.com, No restrictions are applied.

Is it possible to configure postfix server this way?

Comment: You cannot prevent anybody from sending using the ali@comp.com email address. You can only filter emails out that go to priv@example.com and don't have one of the two required senders. I don't know how to do that in postfix, but you can do so using procmail.

Comment: Ok procmail is a good idea. Thanks you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If filtering out based on procmail is acceptable then you can do something like:

```
:0
* ^To:.*priv@example.com
{
  :0
   * ^From:.*ali@comp.com
   * ^From:.*ola@test.org
   maildir_to_deliver_to

  :0
  some_other_maildir_or_dev_null
}
```

(I have not tried this myself, but if you do make sure you test this exhaustively before using `/dev/null` in the last rule to get rid of the 'spam'.